# Customizar Cadastro do Woocommerce!

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Estou com um projeto onde preciso customizar o formulário de cadastro do Woocommerce, o mesmo ja possui email e senha.
Porém preciso adicionar o campo CNPJ e validar se ele é verdadeiro e esta informação deve aparecer também na página de detalhes da conta.

Alguem sabe se isso é possível?

Comment: Você quer desenvolver na mão, programaticamente ou usar algum plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar esse codigo no funcions do seu theme ou plugin, pode adicionar os campos que precisa:

```
     add_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form', 'add_marketplace_fields_to_edit_account_form',1,1);
            function add_marketplace_fields_to_edit_account_form() {
                $user = wp_get_current_user();
                ?>


                <div class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--first form-row form-row-first">
                    <label for="account_first_name"><?php esc_html_e( 'CPF', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
                    <input type="text" v-mask="'###.###.###-##'" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="billing_cpf_cli" v-model="cpf_cli" autocomplete="given-name" />
                </div>
<?php }?>
```

para gravar você pode usar esse hook:

```
function record_custommer_edit( $customer_id ) {



    if (isset($_POST['billing_cpf_cli']) && $_POST['billing_cpf_cli'] != '') {
        update_user_meta($customer_id, 'billing_cpf_cli', sanitize_text_field($_POST['billing_cpf_cli']));
    }

    if (isset($_POST['billing_rg_cli']) && $_POST['billing_rg_cli'] != '') {
        update_user_meta($customer_id, 'billing_rg_cli', sanitize_text_field($_POST['billing_rg_cli']));
    }

}

add_action('woocommerce_update_customer', 'record_custommer_edit');
```